# PIL save as 24 bit true color bitmap

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, gnuplot, xlwt

I have a png file generated by Gnuplot that I need to put into an excel document using XLWT.

XLWT can't import PNG's into the document, only BMP's, so I needed to convert the PNG first. I used PIL for this.

Here's the relevant code:

```
im = Image.open('%s' % os.path.join(os.getcwd(), s + '.png'))
im.save('%s.bmp' % s)
```

However XLWT gives me this error:

```
Exception: bitmap isn't a 24bit true color bitmap.
```

Here's what the XLWT code looks like:

```
self.chart.insert_bitmap(path, 2, 2)
```

I know both images work fine, they're both openable by windows. I've also tried adding a 2 second pause after creating the BMP (to make up for write time), but it still fails.

How do I go about making a 24 bit true color bitmap using PIL?

Answer (score 8):

Nevermind! Just figured it out myself.

Change

```
im = Image.open('%s' % os.path.join(os.getcwd(), s + '.png'))
```

To

```
im = Image.open('%s' % os.path.join(os.getcwd(), s + '.png')).convert("RGB")
```